# Connection to backend and database in android application

Tags: android, backend

I was wondering about how I should set up my backend for my android application.
I was thinking of maybe creating a Webservice which exposes the data from my database, is this a good idea or is there some other way that is more common with mobile applications?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a good idea. Just look at the services, big players like Google, Facebook or Dropbox provide. As data format I prefer JSON over XML as it's easier to create/parse on both sides (especially with Gson).

Comment: Okey, nice. Thinking I will use JSON, but maybe provide both if I decide to make the webservice usable by it self.